# Ionic 4 Ios build fail with with exit code 65 in MacOs

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4 (Angular & Cordova), in my app, I have social login(Google, Facebook, Apple) and firebase for the notification. I am getting this error again and again. here error screenshot.

this error gets when I run build command(ionic cordova build ios)

[image]

> Ionic info

```
mac@macs-iMac foodo_01-12-21 % ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 1.4.0

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v14.17.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.12
   OS      : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode   : Xcode 12.5.1 Build version 12E507

mac@macs-iMac foodo_01-12-21 %
```

> config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.food" version="0.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Food</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
            <application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="pods_ios_min_version" value="9.0" />
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="12" />
        <preference name="pods_use_frameworks" value="true" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Core" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Auth" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Messaging" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Performance" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/RemoteConfig" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/DynamicLinks" version="5.20.0" />
        <pod name="Fabric" version="1.9.0" />
        <pod name="Crashlytics" version="3.12.0" />
        <pod name="GoogleSignIn" version="4.4.0" />
        <config-file parent="GADApplicationIdentifier" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3347511713</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="GADIsAdManagerApp" target="*-Info.plist">
            <true />
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>You can take photos</string>
        </config-file>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="c813693b" />
</widget>
```

I am getting errors in the screenshot please help me to fix this issue.
If need more info please comment, I will share ASAP.

Comment: Share your `config.xml` file so we can take a look. You also haven't stated whether you're running this in simulator or on a real device.

Comment: @Super_Simon check now i have updated.

Comment: Try running `cd platforms/ios && pod install`. Do you get any errors?